# Lisp : Function prints NIL for list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I problem I'm running into is that when I make a function that prints a certain part of a list it prints it as NIL and not the actual element(s).

Ex:

```
> (setf thelist '((a b) (c (d e f)) (g (h i)))
> (defun f1(list)
        (print ( car (list))))
> (f1 thelist)
   NIL
   NIL

But this works: 
> (car thelist)
   (A B)
```

1. Why does it print NIL when thelist is used in the function but when used alone it outputs the first element just fine?
2. How do I get the function to print the part of the list I want out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have:

```
(print (car (list)))
```

This is invoking [the `list` function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_.htm), and *not* using your `list` parameter. `(list)` always returns an empty list. (Common Lisp is a "Lisp-2", which means that `list` in a function-call context refers to a different thing from `list` in a variable-access context.)

To fix, change your code to use:

```
(print (car list))
```

instead.